# Consolidating music from three drives to one

Tags: iphone, music, windows

I am trying to consolidate my music and videos on my Laptop. It is in 3 places:

- C:\Users\RajMore\Music
- D:\Entertainment\Audio
- E:\Entertainment\Audio

I want to put all the music in a single location `C:\Users\RajMore\Music` so that I can carry a single laptop and not have to worry about taking my External HDD or having to remove the D drive to put in my DVD drive.

I have just about 60 GB of music. 10 GB on C, 20 G on D and 30 GB on E. I have 86 GB free on C, so space is not at a premium.

Metadata is the stuff about the music / video that is not stored in the music / video item - it is stored in ITunes.  For example: Start of song, end of song, rating (I use this when for good songs to DJ), video start time and end time etc.

How do I do this and not lose metadata regarding the music and videos?

Comment: @Mark: Question edited for your comment

Comment: metadata stored in music not in iTunes,you just have problem in rating and number of play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Prefs > Advanced set the Media Folder to your chosen location on C:

Then, File Menu > Library SubMenu > Organize Library.

Select "Consolidate Files".